# Pending Intent not working for incoming call in twilio

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I am new to twilio sdk, trying to use it with sdk's sample code with live account credentials,but i am stuck in getting incoming call.
What i have done this twiML config. on server side

```
<Response> <Dial callerId="+91xxxxxxxxxx"> <Client>+91xxxxxxxxx</Client> </Dial> </Response>
```

I had strictly followed the HelloMonkey App source code with my own urls,If i make client to PSTN outbound call it succeeds,but could not make app to app calling.

Comment: You seem to still have a phone number in the `<Client>` element, shouldn't that be a client ID?

Comment: @philnash i had made +91xxxx as friendly name for same no.

Comment: @philnash i had made my custom server config, is there any problem with it ?? if there is ....please tell me

Comment: So clients don't have numbers they have IDs that you set when the client connects through the Twilio Client SDK. That is what you need to use in the TwiML there.

Comment: means i have to buy a no for each user ?

Comment: If you are doing app to app calling you don't need a number at all.

Comment: @philnash i am now bit confused that a user without any no. to recieve calls would still get app to app calling......please explain it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98242/discussion-between-yogesh-seralia-and-philnash).